# Are These Square Brackets Indicating An Indexer?

Tags: c#

```
public class Task : IBusinessEntity
{
    public Task () {}

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}
```

Is the `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]` an indexer in C#?

This code is made to work with SQLlite-NET.

Would the index be defined in `IBusinessEntity` or whatever that inherits from?

Comment: they are called `Attributes`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called attributes.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) is the documentation from Microsoft, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) is a tutorial about them.

You can declare them at a class level like this (code from MSDN tutorial):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class HelpAttribute : System.Attribute
```

Or at a method-level:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SomeWebMethod([System.Web.Services.WebMethod(
   Description="Describe what your method does here.")])
```

Or, at the member-level like you have already declared above.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

Those are attributes. They serve to provide metadata about the member to other parts of the application. You decorate members with attribute keys by placing them in brackets above the member.

Comment: ooo I see, so they decorate the ID field's default getter|setter methods here, thank you.